# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ratingAvg' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have download this project from github but i get this error while running. Its seems that error is on retrieving review from database. 
This project backend is done in nodejs and frontend is done in angularjs.
I have post some of the code which may occur this error and the console of error. 
please help me to solve this problem. 
Thank You so much in advance.

Preview.js

```
exports.getRentalRating = function(req, res) {
  const rentalId = req.params.id;

  Review.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$rental"},
    {"$group": {
      "_id": rentalId,
      "ratingAvg": {"$avg": "$rating"}
    }}], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send({errors: normalizeErrors(err.errors)});
      }

      return res.json(result[0]['ratingAvg'])
    })
}
```

error in console

```
App is running!
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ratingAvg' of undefined
    at E:\bwm-ng\server\controllers\review.js:94:32
    at E:\bwm-ng\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3954:16
    at model.hooks.execPost (E:\bwm-ng\node_modules\mongoose\lib\aggregate.js:811:13)
    at E:\bwm-ng\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: can you check the value of result[0]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a property of a document that does not exist in the results. It seems you don't have any data in `result` or it's not in the structure you expect and are trying to access the items within it.

Please add a `console.log(result);` before you try and return the data. So we can see what data you have, if any.

Change as per:

```
Review.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$rental"},
    {"$group": {
      "_id": rentalId,
      "ratingAvg": {"$avg": "$rating"}
    }}], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(422).send({errors: normalizeErrors(err.errors)});
      }

      console.log(result);

      // check you have data before you attempt to access properties on it
      if(result && result.length > 0) {
          return res.json(result[0]['ratingAvg'])
      }

      // return a empty result etc
      return res.json({});
    })
```